# Navigate to new screen as Modal

Tags: react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have three screens, `HomeScreen`, `ChildModalScreen`, and `ChildCardScreen`.

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigation({
   HomeScreen,
   ChildModalScreen,
   ChildCardScreen
}, {
  mode: 'card',
  headerMode: 'none'
})
```

HomeScreen is initially displayed after app start. I would like to use `this.props.navigation.navigate(...)` to navigate to the other two screens with different animation types, `ChildModalScreen` slide-in from bottom and ChildCardScreen slide-in from right.

I tried to separate `ChildModalScreen` into another stack by setting its config `{ mode: 'modal' }`, but no luck for this.

> as I read the doc, this doesn't not effect on android

Is there any I could make `ChildModalScreen` animate as modal?